# How to override python library class, so other libraries that use it as dependency recieve overriden one

Tags: python, pip

Let's say we have library1 and library2.
Library1 uses library2 as dependency, but library2 has some features or bugs i want to fix.

How do i override library2 class from simple main.py file, so it can be used by anyone without need to fix library files themselves?

(i just changed library2 code in venv folder, and while this is ok for dev build, it's not good for public usage)

as library1 and library2 are installed via pip, there is not so much i can do, as far as i know, without making entire fork of both libraries

Comment: What do you mean by "override", exactly? Do you mean patch?

Answer (score 0):

Monkey patch.  Create a library2 and import it in your code.  Be sure to import it before library1 or library2.

In your library2, import the true library2.  Override anything you wish. expose all of it.